# Laptop will not go to sleep

Tags: windows-11, sleep, process-explorer, svchost, powercfg

I'm new here, so it is a pleasure to meet all of you. I have a Windows 11 computer, and everything else works fine otherwise. However, when I try to make my computer sleep, the screen will only dim itself, but everything else (fans, power button, etc.) will stay on.

After running the command `powercfg -requests` in the Command Prompt, it came back with the following:

```
DISPLAY:
None.

SYSTEM:
[PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\SysWOW64\svchost.exe

AWAYMODE:
[PROCESS] \Device\HarddiskVolume3\Windows\SysWOW64\svchost.exe

EXECUTION:
None.

PERFBOOST:
None.

ACTIVELOCKSCREEN:
None.
```

When checking Process Explorer, I've also noticed that almost all of the svchost.exe processes were highlighted in red except three of them. Two of the three gives an error if I hover my mouse over it, but the last one shows the same directory as shown in the Command Prompt, with the PID being 17008.

I have no idea what I can do to allow my computer to sleep again. Is the svchost.exe a virus? If so, what can I do to remove it? I don't want to reinstall Windows 11, so if there are any alternative solutions, I am more than willing to try them out.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I should probably add that in my Windows Security Exclusions, the process ```svchost.exe``` is also included. I was not able to remove the exclusion until I went into my Registry Editor and manually deleted the key from the folder.